# Doctrine 2 @Version doesn't work

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm

I tried to implement a versionable ORM using Doctrine2.

Everything works well. When I update an existing entry the old entry gets inserted into the *_version table.

But when I update the entry in another request (and therefor a new instance of `EntityManager`) the old entry won't be written anymore to the `*_version` table although the entry in the basic table gets updated without any problems (even the version no. gets incremented by 1).

I like to show you my very simple versionable ORM:

**UPDATE: The example code below works now!**

[Also check my Gist with the `logEntityVersion` helper method.](https://gist.github.com/TiMESPLiNTER/dfc8d2ac570481520f12)

**ProductBase.php**

```
trait ProductBase
{
    /** 
     * @ORM\Id 
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    protected $id;
    /** 
     * @ORM\Column(type="string") 
     */
    protected $name;

    // getters and setters here
}
```

**Product.php**

```
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Product
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="product")
 * @ORM\HasLifeCycleCallbacks
 */
class Product
{
    use ProductBase;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ProductVersion", mappedBy="product", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $auditLog;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Version
     */
    private $version = 1;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->auditLog = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function logVersion()
    {
        echo sprintf("Creating a new version for ID %s, version %s\n", $this->getId(), $this->getVersion());
        $this->auditLog[] = new ProductVersion($this);
    }

    // Version getter and setter
}
```

**ProductVersion.php**

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * ProductVersion
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="product_version")
 */
class ProductVersion
{
    use ProductBase;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Product", inversedBy="auditLog")
     */
    private $product;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $version;

    public function __construct(Product $product)
    {
        $this->product = $product;
        $this->name = $product->getName();
        $this->version = $product->getVersion();

        var_dump($product->getVersion());
    }

    // Version getter and setter
}
```

And this is the code for inserting a new entry and update it to create a new version:

```
// Insert new product
$this->entityManager->beginTransaction();
$this->entityManager->flush();

$product = new Product();
$product->setName('Product V1');

$this->entityManager->persist($product);
$this->entityManager->flush();

$this->entityManager->commit();

$productId = $product->getId();

echo "Created Product with ID " . $product->getId() . "\n";

/** @var Product $foo */
$foo = $this->entityManager->getRepository('orm\Product')->find($productId);

// Log version (Product V1)
$this->entityManager->beginTransaction();
$this->entityManager->flush();
$foo->logVersion();
$this->entityManager->flush();
$this->entityManager->commit();

// Update 1
$foo->setName('Product V2');
$this->entityManager->flush();

// Log version (Product V2)
$this->entityManager->beginTransaction();
$this->entityManager->flush();
$foo->logVersion();
$this->entityManager->flush();
$this->entityManager->commit();

// Update 2 
$foo->setName('Product V3');
$this->entityManager->flush();
```

**Schema generation**

```
$tools = new SchemaTool($this->entityManager);

var_dump($tools->getCreateSchemaSql(array(
    $this->entityManager->getClassMetadata('orm\Product'),
    $this->entityManager->getClassMetadata('orm\ProductVersion')
)));
```

Comment: Have you tried to add the cascade persist annotation on the onetomany relations?

Comment: @Matteo Yes have tried that but didn't change anything.

Comment: very strange, possibly a problem in the chain of the event listener? try to explicit call the `logVersion()` method before persist, (only for a test)

Comment: @Matteo Okay you got it.  I have to create the versions manually by calling the `logVersion()` method :-). But there's still a problem that the `version` field in the `*_version` table stays `1` with each version. But the `version` field in the base table gets incremeted. Strange.

Although I think this should be done automatically. Anyway I found a related issue in the bug tracker of Doctrine2: http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-871

Comment: very strange, i hope you find a better solutions than call directly the logversion method.  Good luck

Comment: @Matteo Okay I managed that it works without calling the `logVersion()` method manually. But still the `version` column in the `*_version` table won't be incremented. I found this hint in the doc `DQL UPDATE statements are ported directly into a Database UPDATE statement and therefore bypass any locking scheme, events and do not increment the version column. Entities that are already loaded into the persistence context will NOT be synced with the updated database state. It is recommended to call EntityManager#clear() and retrieve new instances of any affected entity.` But I don't do DQL afaik

Comment: Okay another problem I've found is that if I edit the entries in a second request (new instance of entity manager) no new records in `*_version` table get created... only the `version` column in the original table gets an increment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see a couple of issues with your code, and unfortunately the concept as well:

#### Array vs Collection

You've defined `Product::$auditLog` as an array, but it needs to be a Collection. Use this in stead:

```
class Product
{
    private $auditLog;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->auditLog = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }
```

#### Association mapping

You've defined `Product::$auditLog` as being mapped by `ProductVersion::$product`, but haven't defined `ProductVersion::$product` as being inversed by `Product::$auditLog`. Fix it like this:

```
class ProductVersion
{
    /** @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Product", inversedBy="auditLog") */
    private $product;
```

Also, please validate your mappings and database schema. Every error might lead to unexpected results.

```
$ doctrine orm:validate-schema          // plain Doctrine2
$ app/console doctrine:schema:validate  // Symfony2
```

#### Versioning

You're using the `@Version` annotation in the trait, meaning both `Product` and `ProductVersion` will be versioned by Doctrine. As `@Version` is used for optimistic locking, I doubt this is what you're really after.

Records in an audit-log should never be updated (or deleted), only added. So locking records doesn't really make sense here.

Please remove `ProductBase::$version` and in stead add:

- `Product::$version` with `@Version` annotation.
- `ProductVersion::$version` **without** `@Version` annotation.

Now only `Product` will be versioned by Doctrine, `ProductVersion` will simply contain the version-number of the product that is logged.

#### PreUpdate event

You're using `@PrePersist` and `@PreUpdate` lifecycle callbacks to populate the audit-log. `@PreUpdate` is going to be a problem, as the [docs](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/events.html#preupdate) state:

> Changes to associations of the updated entity are never allowed in this event

Yet you are changing the `Product::$auditLog` association by adding a record to the collection.

You'll have to move this logic, and there are many options as to *where to*:

One option could be to start a transaction manually, flush (and keep track of versioned entities), create log entries, flush again, commit the transaction. Or you could replace the second flush with direct inserts using the DBAL connection.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I improved the code along your sugestions (updated code in my initial question). It now logs all version but still gets confused with the `version` column in the `*_version` table because this column doesn't increment or just sometimes. I'm not sure if I understood your `PreUpdate event` thing right. Maybe you can have a look at the code above.

Comment: Using the PreUpdate event to create a new entity and add it to the collection/association _will_ have unexpected results, the docs warn about that. You'll have to do it _outside_ of that flush operation.

Comment: `ProductVersion::$version` is probably not incremented because the PreUpdate callback is called _before_ Doctrine handles the @Version on `Product::$version`.

Comment: I finally managed it. (Updated my code above with an inelegant spaghetti code  example which is working). Thank you so much for your help :-). Although this behavior of doctrine2 is not very dev-friendly.

Comment: Yes, that's the gist of it :) You'd probably want to wrap that up in a service somewhere.

Comment: Yeah probably I'm going to create a helper class like `my\DoctrineHelper::logVersion($entityManager, $obj)` or something like this...